Homotopy equivalence splitting for acyclic complexes

In the first three lines of the proof, it's not clear to me how the author conludes that $ZK$ is a direct summand (nor the fact that the sequence splits). The text previously explains that a sequence splits if there are 'backwards' maps in the short exact sequence which serve as left/right inverses; however, I don't see how is this used here. Also since K is the middle term in s.e.s, doesn't it make sense for K to split? I will very much appreciate it if someone could elaborate on the steps involved!

Your understanding is correct: K splits. For $Z_nK$ to be a summand of $K_n$ means that $K_n$ can be expressed as a direct sum of $Z_nK$ and something else, in this case $B_nK$. Dold constructs a section in the s.e.s., so the sequence splits, and so the forward direction has been proved.

Splitting via backwards maps is equivalent to having direct sum in the middle.  This is an easy/good exercise.

Please provide the author’s name, etc.: provide proper attribution whenever you quote someone else’s work.
